# Full absolute path to file's parent directory in PHP

Tags: php, global-variables

I need to return full absolute path to file's parent directory by PHP, which should include protocol, domain address and path to the file. Purpose could be to automatically generate a link so it could be appended to social networks sharer link, regardless of site's domain migration.

`$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` will get domain name, and `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` will get path along with php file using it. `realpath()` will get again full path from server document root, and `dirname()` will get path without file itself. So the best I could think of was:

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])
```

Is there anything better or shorter? And, I still need a protocol. I only came up with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']`, which I see discussed on other questions as not reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this one? Covers https and your path (without file name)

```
$url = "http".(($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s" : "")."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."/";
```

Comment: no problem! glad i could help (without being able to test it ;)